# The Secret Passcode

Tags: lateral-thinking, password

A top secret facility is guarded by 1 man, this man will kill anyone with the wrong, or without a, passcode.

There are 5 spies. They have determined the code is one of the following;

1. Orange
2. Apple
3. Red
4. 5
5. TV
6. Complicator

Each spy guessed in the order specified above.

The last spy got it right. How did he do it?

Comment: "Each spy guessed in the order they tried" - does this mean spy 1 guessed Orange, 2 guessed Apple, 5 guessed TV?

Comment: You're on the right track... Sorry if that was hard to understand.

Comment: I think there is something left unclear here. Apparently the answer relies on the each person knowing what the others guessed, and whether or not it was correct. In that case, assuming the spies aren't stupid, the only way the last spy can *lose* is if the others are wrong and then he guesses the only remaining wrong answer.

Comment: I see the answer is accepted, but I don't get it. If spy #2 guessed "apple" did he die or not?  And did the spies #1-5 die?  Is spy #6 the only one who didn't die?

Comment: @BGM Edited both the question and answer to help you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The answer is

> "one" of the list. Number 1 is Orange, so the first spy got it right on the first day, all the subsequent spies saw he didn't die which meant that each spy was able to get through unharmed - not just the last spy.

Comment: Bingo! Great job!